# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, hadoop, hbase

I have created Java Web Service v2.5 using **Axis2** runtime and **Tomcat 7** as web server on **Eclipse**. For normal @WebMethod it is working as expected means I can call it from client(In my case its .NET Client) but for methods in which I have used HBASE connectivity snippets its throwing error as:

```
[ERROR] org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
at Hbase.HbaseUploader.GetScannerResultsInDictionary(HbaseUploader.java:164)
... 32 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
... 33 more
```

I am kinda confused here like:

1) If my web service has some problem then why client can successfully invoke other methods.

2) And if there is a problem in HBASE CLASSPATH then why can I run same snippet in Non-Web Service environment (if I execute same code in console application it is working fine)

Please help me out.

Comment: How are you executing the code in the console?

Comment: I am creating plain Java console application and using the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing following I am successfully running my JWS on Tomcat:

```
1) Configured Build Path for dynamic web service(Add Jars in Order and Export)
2) Added JARs in Deployment Assembly
```

This is required because the JARs should be there in WAR in deployment.
This was a blunder because I am newbie to Java.